# How do I import existing project into SVN repository?

Tags: svn

I've been following [this guide](http://bookofzeus.com/articles/subversion/create-a-svn-repository-with-ubuntu-and-subversion/) for installing SVN in Ubuntu.  I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I have an existing java project in my workspace:

```
/home/plattens/workspace/jguids30ma
```

I've created a repository for the project:

```
svnadmin create /svn/repository/jguids30ma
```

But so far all my attempts to import the existing project into the repository have failed.

```
svn import /svn/repository/jguids30ma/ file:///home/plattens/workspace/jguids30ma -m "Initial check in"
```

Resulting in:

```
svn: E180001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///home/plattens/workspace/jguids30ma'  
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL  
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/plattens/workspace/jguids30ma'
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Aren't you using the paths in the wrong order? I think it should be `svn import /home/plattens/workspace/jguids30ma file:///svn/repository/jguids30ma/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to launch `svnserve` like this:

```
svnserve -d -r /svn/repository/jguids30ma
```

From [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html):

> Once we successfully start svnserve as explained previously, it makes every repository on your system available to the network. A client needs to specify an absolute path in the repository URL. For example, if a repository is located at /var/svn/project1, a client would reach it via svn://host.example.com/var/svn/project1

So you should try to use svn protocol instead of file like this:

```
svn import /svn/repository/jguids30ma/ svn://[IP of your server]/home/plattens/workspace/jguids30ma -m "Initial check in"
```

Comment: I get: svnserve: E000098: Can't bind server socket: Address already in use.

Comment: okay its probably because you have already started svnserve and it's already running in the background. So you can kill the process and restart it. To find PID run `ps -ef | grep svnserve` and kill it with `sudo kill PID`

Comment: Now I get "svn: E170001: Authorisation failed"